# Typescript with SystemJS: Cannot find own module

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I developed an module and now I want to take this module out of the app and into node_modules. But there is an error `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bipartite-graph'.` where `bipartite-graph` is my own module.

This is my `systemjs.config.ts`:

```
SystemJS.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './app.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'bipartite-graph': {
      main: './bipartite-graph.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    'rxjs': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  map: {
    app: 'app',

    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',

    'bipartite-graph': 'app/bipartite-graph'
  }
});
```

And this is the `app.ts`:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import BipartiteGraph from 'bipartite-graph';

let subject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
let bg = new BipartiteGraph([35, 50, 40], [45, 20, 30, 30], [[8, 6, 10, 9], [9, 12, 13, 7], [14, 9, 16, 5]]);

const n = 3, m = 4;

let i = 1, j = 1;
while (i <= n && j <= m) {
  bg.setAmount(i, j, Math.min(bg.getCapacity(i), bg.getDemand(j)));
  bg.setCapacity(i, bg.getCapacity(i) - bg.getAmount(i, j)); bg.setDemand(j, bg.getDemand(j) - bg.getAmount(i, j));
  if (bg.getCapacity(i) === 0) {
    i = i + 1;
  } else {
    j = j + 1;
  }
}

bg.draw();
```

The project transpiles and the final app works without errors but Webstorm und tsc throw the error. I imported `rxjs` to compare but I can't find a crucial difference. What am I missing? I tried to put the module into `node_modules` and changed the path in `systemjs.config.ts` but it didn't help. The whole project can be found on [project](https://github.com/jabaa/bipartite-graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typescript compiler does not find your `bipartite-graph` module because it's not reading your systemJS config. You have to add a `tsconfig.json` file, if not already there, with the baseUrl and path options set.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "bipartite-graph": ["app/bipartite-graph"],
      ...other path mappings
    }
  }
}
```

more on this topic can be found in the official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html